# I created from Buildozer, the terminal is saying bash: no such file or directory

Tags: python, optimization, kivy, apk

I am not able to optimise my apk that I created using Buildozer. when is use the optimize command:

```
$ ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign -v 4 ./bin/Your-App-0.1-release.apk ./bin/Your-App-0.1-release-optimized.apk
```

its saying bash :

```
no such file or directory.
```

plus I don't know which sdk I'm using. my project location is Desktop/mobileapp/bin/TibetanAstroCalendar-0.1-Release-unsigned.apk (I created the release version

and one more question : - from which directory do I need to run the optimize command

Comment: Probably need to change `./bin/Your-App-0.1-release.apk` in that command to `./bin/TibetanAstroCalendar-0.1-Release-unsigned.apk`

Comment: The questions I asked was edited by some one. and given some wrong information. my main apk file is in a folder called mobileapp which is on the desktop of the kivy virtual machine. the command initial command ~buildozer  is I guess going into the folder called buildozer which is on the home ,, but there is no folder called buildozer in my vm home

Comment: can you please suggest the code. The information are as follows:-  1. location of app is home/kivy/desktop/mobileapp/bin/ and apk name is TibetanAstroCalendar-1.0-release-unsigned.apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest installing the `zipalign` package. In Ubuntu, that would simply be:

```
sudo apt-get install zipalign
```

Then do:

```
cd home/kivy/desktop/mobileapp/bin
zipalign -v -p 4 TibetanAstroCalendar-1.0-release-unsigned.apk aligned.apk
```

That is based on your provided information, but perhaps that directory is /home/kivy/desktop/mobileapp/bin? Is a leading `/` missing? You can replace the name `aligned.apk` with any file name you like.

If you cannot or do not want to install the `zipalign` package, look for any `zipalign` under `.buildozer` in your home directory, then replace `zipalign` with the path to the `zipalign` you found.

Some versions of `zipalign` do not recognize the `-p` option. If you get an `unrecognized option` error, just leave off the `-p`.

Comment: when I try to install the zipalign its giving an error . unable to fetch some archives maybe run apt-get update or try --fix-missing. Which directory do you mean by the home . There is a directory called home in my system , but there is nothing called buildozer but only a folder called kivy

Comment: So do what it suggested. run `sudo apt-get update`, then retry the `install`. The directory we are talking about is not `buildozer` it is `.buildozer` (notice the leading `.`). Directories with  a leading `.` are normally not shown, but `ls -a` will show all directories.

Comment: sudo apt-get is not also working bro. Maybe the problem is that I'm using the kivy virtual machine?

Comment: Didn't know you are actually on Windows. Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916462/how-to-zipalign-the-apk-file-in-windows).

Comment: or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988837/buildozer-unsigned-release-apk-saved-in-windows-folder-now-need-to-zipalign-and)

Comment: I'm on a Mac . thanks for your good response and helpful nature

Comment: please help me fast I'm in a big trouble coz I need to publish this app today and need to show it tomorror

Comment: Hey , thanks I was able to solve this. actually the problem was that my version was 20 and the file inside the build tools was 19.1.0 , I was just typing the build tool version 21.0.1. Thank you John Anderson